# Token invalid : Token must be in class <'bytes'>

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to decode the token from the user.Every Time I run the code it show Decode error

```
class PasswordChange(generics.GenericAPIView):
    model = CustomUser
    serializer_class = PasswordChangeSerializer
    
    def patch(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        payload = jwt.decode(serializer['token'], settings.SECRET_KEY,algorithms=['HS256'])
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
        if user.check_password(serializer['old_password']):
            user.set_password(serializer['new_password'])
            user.save()
```

Comment: try encoding the serializer['token'] ==> serializer['token'].encode()

Comment: it's not working

Comment: are you sure the token is valid and not a wrong string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as the docs say you can get the token form the request by accessing the 'auth' property on the request: 'request.auth' so if you need the access token you should get it like these: (access = request.auth.token) , then decode it as you did in your code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).